# Sorcerers in Small world

Tags: small-world

If i play sorcerers can I first roll the dice (like at the final move), capture new territory and only after it change my sorcerer for another enemy unit who became a neighbor only after this final conquest?

Answer (score 4):

No you can not. The conquest in which you roll a die must be the final conquest of your turn. From the rules:

> During the final conquest attempt of his turn, a player may find himself with not enough Race tokens left to conquer another Region outright. Provided he still has at least one unused Race token, the player may attempt one tinal conquest for his turn by selecting a Region that he would normally be 3 or less Race tokens short to conquer. Once the Region is selected, the player rolls the Reinforcement Die once. Note that the Region the player wishes to make his last conquest target for the turn must be selected before rolling the die. This Region does not have to be the weakest one available for attack either, provided it could still be conquered with a lucky die roll.
>
> If the sum of the die rolled, combined with the Race token(s) left in his possession, is high enough to conquer the Region, the player deploys his remaining Race token(s) there. Otherwise, he deploys his remaining token(s) in one of the Regions he already occupied prior. Either way, **his conquests for the turn end immediately thereafter**.

And a sorcerer using his power is a type of conquest:

> Once per turn per opponent, your sorcerers **can conquer a Region by** substituting one of your opponent's Active tokens with one of your own taken from the storage tray.